# Dynamic jwt expiration in micronaut security

Tags: java, jwt, micronaut

I know how to set the expiration time of a JWT when using micronaut security by configuring `micronaut.security.token.jwt.generator.access-token-expiration`. But how can I set that dynamically with every token generation, e.g. based on the user's role?